# vue: command not found error on MacOS with Vue-CLI global installation

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli-3

First, I checked all related questions and articles on web but couldn't find a proper solution.

I install Vue-CLI3 using `npm install -g @vue/cli` and it's done with this output: `@vue/cli@3.7.0`

`npm list -g --depth=0` command gives that output:

```
├── @vue/cli@3.7.0
├── eslint@5.16.0
├── jshint@2.10.2
├── npm@6.9.0
├── npx@10.2.0
└── typescript@3.4.5
```

When I run `vue --version` it says `-bash: vue: command not found`.

I tried to uninstall & reinstall Vue, but it didn't help.

I think something is missing on my bash_profile, but I don't know what to add exactly.

`which vue` command doesn't return anything btw.

Comment: Add `vue` binary in your PATH

Comment: Can you give an example that shows how to add it, please?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and I do not know Why I have missing packages. But I resolved it with `npm install -g pnpm`.

Then you can run `npm install -g @vue/cli` or `vue --version`